# Confusion about operators and representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

Physics student here. In my textbook on group theory, there was a matrix
 $$h_1=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1/2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then the author define the operator $H_1=D(h_1)$ where D is an irreducible representation of the Lie algebra of SU(3). I can't understand why they defined it as such. I know that the matrix $h_1$ is the 3rd generator of the Lie algebra of SU(3), that is $\frac{1}{2}\lambda_3 $. Thanks.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: You've used both $i$ and $1$ as a subscript. And I have no idea how $\lambda_3$ (which I would expect to be an eigenvalue) is a generator of the Lie algebra. You need to fill in a lot of details, please.

Comment: @TedShifrin it was a mistake i meant $h_1$.By $\lambda_3$ i mean the Gell-Mann matrix $lambda_3 $ as seen here   (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices)

Comment: How come your answer about the textbook has been removed?

Comment: @Shaun Howard Georgi "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" i didn't write the full name, my bad

Answer (score 1):

What you have written down is the triplet  (fundamental, defining) SU(3) representation of $h_1$, the first Cartan subalgebra generator.

It is called the isospin generator for the triplet in physics-speak. I'm not sure what troubles you. You should be able to write the octet (adjoint) representation of the *same* generator, as well, given the structure constants of the su(3) Lie algebra.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I know that there is a second Cartan subalgebra generator, namely the $T^8=1/2\lambda_8$ with $\lambda_8$ being the 8th Gell-Mann matrix. What troubled me was tge notation,i.e $H_1=D(h_1)$.

Comment: I don't have the book (and, frankly, you should be learning from a different one). But the matrix you write *is* $D_3(h_1)$, certainly *not* $h_1$: Lie algebra elements are *not* matrices.